# what is customer_reference used for

Tags: magento-enterprise, customer, eav

been looking into the attributes customers use in magento, in the build we have we have a references attribute which we created for card references however every created customer is also given a customer_reference which has is system set to true

in customer_entity_varchar the value is blank (not null, just blank) and i can't find customer_reference in the backend, so i am wondering what it's used for and also how i can stop it from adding data to the database since we have 300,000 customers and we don't want useless eav attributes hanging around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irrespective of the attribute being listed as "is system" in the user interface, I'm looking at a stock installation of Magento 1.7.x and there's no such attribute as `customer_reference`.  As such, my (educated) guess is this was something added via a custom module and/or customer development, which means you're not likely to find an answer here.

Comment: that might explain how it exists but isn't used, maybe customer_reference was a prototype of references but was left in there, also i didn't know "is system" also dealt with eav attributes added in via modules, i'll look around the custom modules and find out which one is creating it

Comment: @Memor-X It's been a while, but I'm pretty sure "is system" just reflects the value of `is_user_defined` in the `eav_attribute` table.